# Issue extracting special character with Apex Data Loader 28.0.2

Tags: data-loader

I am getting issue's with the extracted .csv files from Apex Data-Loader:

While extracting data that contains special characters, the exported .csv file doesn't show the special character as they were seen in Salesforce UI, but they can changed to something different special character. [ so how to extract them as they were seen in salesforce UI ]

The another thing is one of my client getting this problem, when they are extracting the data(containing Korean language) from dataloader in .csv file the data got broken with many rows when we open it with correct procedure as mentioned below:

```
a. Opening a new excel sheet, then going to "Data" tab and then clicking on 'From Text' option
b. Then selecting the file(,csv extracted by dataloader) and using these settings:-
c. Step 1: Delimited & File Origin- 65001: Unicode(UTF-8)
d. Step 2: Delimeter - Tab and Comma
e. Step 3: Column data format - Text for text type data and Data for date type data
```

Please help me with these issue's.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are not writing the CSV file using the correct encoding.

From the online help

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jRNIAA2

1. Make sure the 2 UTF-8 encoding setting in Data Loader are checked.

Read all CSVs with encoding
Write all CSVs with encoding

1. Perform Export.and save the file on local file folder

3 Open Excel and import the file,  on the MS Excel Import Wizard step 3, choose the File Origin Unicode (UTF-8).

Once the CSV is exported and displays symbols when opening in Excel. You may try these steps.

Right click on the csv file and click "Open With" 
Choose Notepad 
On Notepad click File then Save As 
Set the file name - (Filename here).csv 
Select UTF-8 on Encoding and click Save 
Open the new CSV file on Excel.

Comment: The information you have given is seems good for the second point, does this same sol. applies to the first one also

Comment: Both things look like the same problem to me.

Comment: ok, I'll try this.

Comment: Sorry to post comment on this after a long time:
But I am getting the same 2nd point mentioned above problem as before I haven't got a time to test the 2nd Point mentioned by me, the special character's are getting correctly displayed but the data in rows are broken into next line for many records. Please give me a workaround on how to extract the data with special character's without being broken in many lines under rows. Thanks